# Download image from firebase using uid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to show profile image in my `tableview` beside the name of the user.

I have uploaded my image to Firebase storage and stored the images URL in Firebase database. Everything works perfectly.
Profile image uploads in firebase Storage and the URL saves in a database but there is something wrong with downloading code because profile image does not appear when I run my app. I don't get any error from `Xcode`.

```
if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl{
        let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!,
            completionHandler:
            {(data, response, error) in

                //download hit error
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
        }).resume()
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Did you checked the url that you are using to download image is Actually working in browser or not ? as according to me there Is something wrong with the url that you are storing in DB of a user

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [SDWebImageView](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
import SDWebImage

cell?.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user.profileImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but Xcode give me error when i try to import SDWebImageView

Comment: No such module 'SDWebImage'

Comment: First, you need to download the library and integrate with your project. Library URL already provided in my answer. Again I provide the library URL https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice. Use `Glide` for downloading the pictures. It is as easy as :

```
Glide.with(ExampleActivity).load(url).into(imageView);
```